# Catch custom exceptions in method.invoke()

Tags: java, exception

If I use method.invoke to invoke a method that throws a custom exception A. What are the ways to catch this exception and handle it in the try catch surrounding method.invoke? The only way I can think of is to catch all Exceptions and check the Exception type;

```
try{
 ...
 method.invoke
 ...
} catch (A e) {

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
try {
    method.invoke
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
   Throwable mainException = e.getCause();
   if (mainException instanceof .....) {
   }
}
```

InvocationTargetException is the wrapper for the exception thrown by the method.

In your case mainException will be of type *A*.

Comment: or `try{ throw e.getCause(); } catch(A a){}`

Comment: Amir is correct, have a read of the Javadoc for which exceptions are thrown in which cases. Obviously, you'll need to handle any checked exceptions! :)